# CSS Checkbox style to toggle a value

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, styles

I am currently writing a program which toggles a value based on the status of a checkbox. With a normal checkbox everything works fine.

HTML:

```
<td><script> checkbox('px_THPressure_Enable')</script></td>
<td><script> checkbox('px_THPressure_Activate')</script></td>
```

Javascript checkbox function:

```
function checkbox(register)
{
var onClicked = "setDataJQuery('"+register+"',this.checked?'1':'0')";
var output = "<input type='checkbox' class='fetch' onClick=\""+onClicked+"\" id='" + register + "'>";
document.write(output);
}
```

Now I am trying to style the checkbox with CSS as described here http://www.paulund.co.uk/style-checkboxes-with-css "Checkbox Four"

So now my checkbox function changed to:

```
function checkbox(register)
{
var onClicked = "setDataJQuery('"+register+"',this.checked?'1':'0')";
var output = "<div class='checkboxFour'><input type='checkbox' class='fetch' value='1' onClick=\""+onClicked+"\" id='" + register + "' name=''></input><label for='checkboxFourInput'></label></div>";

document.write(output);
}
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
visibility: hidden;
}
/**
* Checkbox Four
*/
.checkboxFour {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: #ddd;
margin: 20px 90px;
border-radius: 100%;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
/**
* Create the checkbox button
*/
.checkboxFour label {
display: block;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 100px;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 5px;
z-index: 1;
background: #333;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
/**
* Create the checked state
*/
.checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
background: #26ca28;
}
```

Now I am able to see the correct status of the checkbox with the new style but when I click the checkbox the value does not change. I know that the issue is in the id field. The checkbox style requires the id="checkboxFourInput" and my program requires the id to equal the register value which is being toggled. ie THPressure_Enable

I know that having multiple ids on an html element is not allowed, so is there any way that I can toggle this register value with the styled checkbox.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

It is a function that will change the register value depending on the correct authorization. I have the function defined as follows:

```
function setDataJQuery(register,value)
{
statusElem = document.getElementById('status');
if (statusElem)
statusElem.innerHTML=" ";

//alert("logged in as " + "<?php echo \"{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}\"; ?>");
if (((user_name == 'slipsmart' || user_name== 'slipsmart_super') && (operator_set_ok.indexOf(register.substring(3)) != -1)) || 
(user_name == 'slipsmart_super' && (supervisor_set_ok.indexOf(register.substring(3)) != -1)) ||
user_name == 'slipsmart_setup')
{
$.ajax({
url: 'set.php?' + register + '=' + value,
type: 'post',
success:function(data){
  var val_pairs = data.split("&");
  document.getElementById('Error').innerHTML=" ";
  for (i in val_pairs)
  {
    var pair = val_pairs[i].split("=");
var myElem = document.getElementById(pair[0]);

if (myElem)
    myElem.innerHTML= pair[1];
  }
  }

  }); 
}
else
alert("Not authorized!");
}
```

Comment: What is the intent of this setDataJQuery? Do you have it defined?

Comment: Now I know that it has something to do with the onClick since the css for the backround change of the button doesn't seem to be changing. Should I modify the javascript when the button is pressed to somehow call the css class 
.checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
 background: #26ca28;
}